# ElasticSearch - Query to get documents based on a sum of nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the next document:

```
{
  id: 222,
  email: user@user.com,
  experiences: [
    {
      id: 3,
      position: "Programmer",
      description: "Programming things"
      init_date: "1990-01-01",
      end_date: "1999-05-11"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      position: "Full Stack Developer",
      description: "Programming things"
      init_date: "1999-01-01",
      end_date: "2008-05-11"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      position: "Gardener",
      description: "Taking care of flowers"
      init_date: "2009-01-01",
      end_date: "2015-05-11"
    },
  ]
}
```

So, I would like to do the next filter: **keyword: programming, experience years: > 3**

The experience years should be the sum of the experiences that match the keyword.

Is it possible to do in only one query?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of Indexing itself you add one extra field for experience, Instead of calculating with query. It will be faster easy to query also.